# Spring security exception handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to create spring secured application

I implemented SecurityConfig like this

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

My JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint to handle exception's :

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also I implemented UserDetail Service

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usernameOrEmail)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmail(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException
                                ("User not found with username or email : " + usernameOrEmail)
                );

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }}
```

It was working fine before I added ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice   {

  /****    500   Entity  */
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public final ErrorDetail handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("An unexpected error occurred", ex);

        ErrorDetail problem = new ErrorDetail("Internal Error",
                "An unexpected error has occurred");
        problem.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());

        return problem;
    }
}
```

Now spring is trying to handle Exception in controller advice.  As a consequence, I can not handle the error correctly. if I comment out  Controller advice logic then AuthenticationEntryPoint is processed authentication error.

How can make AuthenticationEntryPoint and @ControllerAdvice work together?

Comment: Why are you using a custom jwt security filter when spring security already has one built in? Please read the chapter on JWTs in the spring security documentation and implement it as the documentation states.